# Error when logging in the user as a consecuence of password hashing

Tags: php, hash

I'm trying to log in this user which username and password are saved in the database but there is a problem! When i try to log in even though a user is registered it says always invalid username.I think this happens because when i registered the user i used password hashing md5 .I have used md5 in the registration form but how can I change this code in a way that it recognises the user password in the login form?Thanks in advance!
This is my code:

```html
<html >
<head>
<title></title>
</head>




<body>
<?php
print ("<form action='logincontroltest.php' method='post'>
    <p>Username
        <input type='text' name='username' />
    </p>
    <p>Password
        <input type='password' name='password' >
        <p/>
    <input type='submit' value='Log In'/>
</form>");

if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
   print("Could not connect");
if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password']) )
{
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);


    if ( !empty($username) &&!empty($password) ) 
    {
         $query = " SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE   `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'";
         if($result=mysql_query($query,$database))
         {

$user=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($user==false){
  echo "invalid username";
}

elseif($user['admin']==1){
  
  echo"admin is logged in";
    header("Location: admin.php");
    
  }
  elseif($user['approval']==1) {
    $_POST['user']=$user['username'];
    echo "user is logged in";
    header("Location: faqja2.php");
  }
  else{
    echo "Your account is'nt approved by admin yet";
    }} 
     die (mysql_error());
          }

   else echo "Fill in all blank fields";
   } 
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my registration php file

```html
<?php
if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
   print("Could not connect");

if(isset($_POST['firstname'] )&&isset($_POST['lastname'])&&isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])
  &&isset($_POST['cv'])/*&&isset($_POST['notat'])&&isset($_POST['lendet'])*/&&isset($_POST['email'])){
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=md5($_POST['password']);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$cv=$_POST['cv'];
/*
$notat=$_POST['notat'];
$lendet=$_POST['lendet'];
*/

$query = "INSERT INTO  login (firstname, lastname, username,password,cv,email) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname',
 '$username','$password','$cv','$email')";
}
if ( !empty($firstname)&&!empty($lastname)&&!empty($username) &&!empty($password)&&!empty($cv)&&!empty($email))
{
  if(!($result=mysql_query($query,$database)))
{
    print("Could not execute query");
    die (mysql_error());//ose error
}

$to='backa.elda123@gmail.com';
$subject='Asking for permission';
$body='There is another registered student waiting for your approval!';
$headers='From:<arbi.backa@gmail.com>';
if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
  echo "mail sent to..";}
  else echo'errorr sending the email';
echo "YOU HAVE BEEN REGISTERED SUCCESSFULLY!PLEASE WAIT FOR THE ADMIN APPROVAL!";
}
else echo "Fill in all the blank fields";
mysql_close($database);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't worry bout hacking.That's not the main problem.md5 is required in my homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting the form to 'logincontroltest.php' . Whereas the login process code is in the same file.  So remove the action value from the Form tag. And process the form submission code, only if the $POST array is set. Then it works.

```
        <html >
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>




    <body>
    <?php
    print ("<form action='' method='post'>
        <p>Username
            <input type='text' name='username' />
        </p>
        <p>Password
            <input type='password' name='password' >
            <p/>
        <input type='submit' value='Log In'/>
    </form>");

    if(isset($_POST)) {

    if( !($database=mysql_connect("localhost","root",""))||!(mysql_select_db("st_login",$database))  )
       print("Could not connect");
    if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password']) )
    {
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=md5($_POST['password']);


        if ( !empty($username) &&!empty($password) ) 
        {
             $query = " SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'";
             if($result=mysql_query($query,$database))
             {

    $user=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($user==false){
      echo "invalid username";
    }

    elseif($user['admin']==1){

      echo"admin is logged in";
        header("Location: admin.php");

      }
      elseif($user['approval']==1) {
        $_POST['user']=$user['username'];
        echo "user is logged in";
        header("Location: faqja2.php");
      }
      else{
        echo "Your account is'nt approved by admin yet";
        }} 
         die (mysql_error());
              }

       else echo "Fill in all blank fields";
       } 

    }
        ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Still then same!It says invalid username even though the user is registered into database.But it works when I remove md5 from the registration form and this login form.

Comment: If you are storing the password after converting it to - md5() while registering, then only one thing comes to mind.  How much is the password column length? It will have to be at least char(32).

Comment: Wow! You unbeliavable!How haven't I thought bout this before.Thanks a lot @T.Shah